# HTML video auto play not working

Tags: html, css

Here is my code, but the video is not looping continuously.

```html
<iframe src="files/media/video/moped.webm?&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="400" height="height: 722.375px;" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

I have tried to set `autoplay` to `0` and `1`, but this has not changed anything.

Comment: height="height: 722.375px;" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<video>` element instead:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop>
    <source src="files/media/video/moped.webm" type="video/webm" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
  ?rel=0;&autoplay=1
```

and be careful with a proper value for heigth

```
<iframe src="files/media/video/moped.webm??rel=0;&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;
          title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" 
                width="400" height="722" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```